# Compact differentiable sub manifold with at least two points

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a differentiable submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$ which contains at least two points. How can I show that if $M$ is compact in $\mathbb R^n$ there exists no atlas for $M$ which only consists of one chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the dimension of $M$ is $p$, the existence of such a chart is equivalent to saying that there exists a connected open subset $U$ of $R^p$ and a homeomorphism $f:U\rightarrow M$, since $M$ is compact, $U$ has to be compact. But a non empty open subset of $R^p,p>0$ is not compact.

Comment: Thanks but why do we need the fact that M contains at least two points?

Comment: If M contains only one point $x$ then you have a chart which is defined by $i:R^0\rightarrow M$ which sends the unique element of $R^0$ to $x$.

Comment: Actually, why does $U$ have to be compact just because $M$ is compact?

Comment: Sorry we just got introduced to manifolds, I have no intuition for it. Why is it "bad" for the proof if $M$ only contains one point $x$?